# Jakarta.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am trying to execute a unit test in Quarkus. This test did work before I added a `import.sql` file to get some initial data to work with. However since the `import.sql` file is added, the simple test does not work anymore.

The object that I am trying to work with extends the `PanacheEnity` and normally an ID should be assigned automatically to it when persisting.

This is the test on which it throws an error:

```
@Test
@TestTransaction
public void shouldCreateAndFindPublisher() {
    Long count = Publisher.count();
    int size = Publisher.listAll().size();
    assertEquals(count, size);

    Publisher publisher = new Publisher("name");

    Publisher.persist(publisher);
    assertNotNull(publisher.id);

    assertEquals(count + 1, Publisher.count());
}
```

This is an example of one out of 100 Publishers is added via sql:

```
-- PUBLISHERS
INSERT INTO t_publishers (id, name, created_date) VALUES
(1, 'Programming', '2023-05-23T15:40:00.592040Z'),
```

This is the error:

```
jakarta.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.xxx.quarkus.panache.model.Publisher#1]
    at org.xxx.quarkus.panache.repository.PublisherRepositoryTest.shouldCreateAndFindPublisher
```

I am assuming that the Test is trying to persist a new Publisher with the same ID as is already present in the `import.sql` file, but I would think that the Generation of the ID in the PanacheEntity takes care of this.

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I assume there is a sequence which belongs to the `id` field, and Hibernate using that by `@GeneratedValue`. But in the sql example ids are set manually, instead of calling next value of the sequence. If I'm right, then that is the expected behaviour. Use sequences in the insert statements or just set the sequence value to a greater value.

Comment: It looks like the error is somewhere else? The error points to a test called `shouldCreateAndFindPublisher` not `shouldCreateAndFindArtist`

Comment: @Jhilton I changed the code example. However, the test looks very similar for both Publisher and Artist

Comment: @zforgo Increasing the `ids` in the `import.sql` does work, but that is just a temporary solution. If change the starting id of an imported Publisher to 200 and afterwards I persist 200 Publisher objects, it will throw an error again...

Comment: It would be good to take a look to your Entity and Repository classes, code wise looks ok... I do prefer not to directly set ids in my seed data SQLs and let the db settle things down for generated values

Comment: Not setting the ids is not a possibility since I should be able to link the IDs as a foreign key in other DB objects in the `import.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Search in the create.sql file for the name of the sequence that is being generated. For EXAMPLE:
create sequence t_publishers_SEQ start with 1 increment by 50;

And then, get the name of the sequence and modify in import.sql to something like that:
ALTER SEQUENCE t_publishers_SEQ RESTART WITH 600;